# what is the best pracitse to make reusable react component with different styles using tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, styled-components, clsx

I have a react component with fairly complicated design, styled by [tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) and want to make it reusable with different styles  depending on the value of its parameter which called variant.
what is the best practice in this situation?
1- make a general class then add different css classes in @layer components, one class for each design.
2- change the style directly in the react component using [twMerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-merge) and [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) depending on the parameter which i mentioned earlier.
3- use [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs) with [tailwindCss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

Comment: There are a couple of good articles on creating Tailwind CSS UI components here which may help: https://www.protailwind.com/articles

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I like to do it as it's clean.

##### You can also add this to your VSCode settings if you'd like to have intellisense for custom classes. It works by detecting anything ending in 'classes' as Tailwind styles.

`

```
"tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
[
            "Classes \\=([^;]*);",
            "'([^']*)'"
        ],
        [
            "Classes \\=([^;]*);",
            "\"([^\"]*)\""
        ],
        [
            "Classes \\=([^;]*);",
            "\\`([^\\`]*)\\`"
        ]
    ],
`
```

### Create a component

```js
import React from "react";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";

const baseClasses = `
    min-w-[220px] px-8 py-4
    text-base leading-5 font-semibold
    border-none rounded-md
    cursor-pointer
    disabled:opacity-50
`;

const variationClasses = {
    "black-on-green": `
        ${ baseClasses }
        text-zinc-700
        bg-emerald-300
    `
};

interface Props extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    className?: string;
    variation: keyof typeof variationClasses;
}

const CustomButton = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, Props>(({ children, className, variation, ...rest }, ref) => {
    return(
        <button
            className={ twMerge(variationClasses[variation], className) }
            ref={ ref }
            type="submit"
            { ...rest }>

            { children }
        </button>
    );
});

CustomButton.displayName = "CustomButton";

export { CustomButton };
```